# Fixing "settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details."

Tags: mysql, django, database

I am using mysql as database for my django project hosted in digitalocean

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
creating superuser
```

everything is working. but when i try to open up my site

The error message shows as: `settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.`

I checked all those previous questions and solutions but they didn't worked for me..

Below is my database setting.

Hope someone can help me on that. Thanks! It was working perfectly fine on my localhost

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'newdb_py',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",  # Strict mode
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same settings.DATABASES at your non-local machine? To check it you can run django shell in the target maching and check the value by `from django.conf import settings; print(settings.DATABASES)`

Comment: @AliAsgari I tested the command and I got : 
`{'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 'NAME': 'newdb_py', 'USER': 'root', 'PASSWORD': 'password', 'HOST': 'localhost', 'PORT': '3306', 'OPTIONS': {'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"}, 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None}}}`

its the same value..
As I said.. my other migration commands were working fine.. 
but just the index.html template is throwing that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error, it seems I haven't added the database configuration that I have made in database.py to my settings.py file. The method I was applying was wrong. I have imported settings.py to database.py which was working for local-machine but it didn't worked for server-hosting.

I solved that issue by just adding a header on settings.py file

```
from .database import *
```

P.S: above configuration was done on database.py